# Angular Js: How do I select an expression in an array based on ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

How do I print an expression of an array based on it's assigned id? I have two arrays, one with the id of 11 and the other with 12. How do I get the name expression of the array with the property of 12?

Below is the services module, controller and HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4705/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, myProperties) {

    $scope.name = 'StackOverflow';

    $scope.myProperties = myProperties;

};

myApp.factory('myProperties', function() {

    var myProperties = [
            {
                'name': '3 Bedroom Fixer Upper',
                'city': 'Santa Rosa',
                'id': 11,
                'state': 'CA',
                'date_added': '2/3/14',
                'completion_status': '80%',
                'imgURL': 'http://dfon12yb6dcdf.cloudfront.net/product/kr4f0uv5tkd6slvmn7r9j4h4jj/w1024x683.jpg?v=4',
            },
            {
                'name': '2 Bedroom Condo',
                'city': 'Vallejo',
                'id': 12,
                'state': 'CA',
                'date_added': '4/10/20',
                'completion_status': '50%',
                'imgURL': 'http://dfon12yb6dcdf.cloudfront.net/product/kr4f0uv5tkd6slvmn7r9j4h4jj/w1024x683.jpg?v=4',
            },
        ]

    //return the array here
    return myProperties

});

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
    <br>
    <ul ng-repeat="property in myProperties">
        <li>{{property.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <h3>{{property.id[12]}}</h3>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular's forEach function to compare an ID with each object in an array. Here's the relevant bit.

```
$scope.findObj = function(searchId)
        {
          var resultObj;
          angular.forEach(myProperties, function(obj)
          {
            if ( obj.id == searchId)
            {
              resultObj = obj;
            }
          });
          return resultObj;
        };
```

Demo Plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKid2lC3nGfvJx6oEUB4?p=preview)